# Rich Text Field Adding Tags around script

Tags: field, richtext

I'm trying to add some embed code/script and the rich text field on save puts misc `<p>` tags around my code.

How do I save code so it keeps it's code formatting without adding an extra stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the Redactor [allowedTags](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-allowedTags) config setting to allow `<script>` tags.

You can see how to define custom Redactor configs in Craft [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields#redactor-configs).

Comment: Still had some issues if I turned to code view...ended up just putting embed in template.  Thanks for the help.